# n∈ℕ, p∈ℂ[x], ∀z∈ℂ* show $p(z+\frac{1}{z})=(z^n +\frac{1}{z^n})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, contest-math

With $n∈ℕ$, Show that there exist a unique polynomial $p∈ℂ[x] $such that $∀z∈ℂ^*$, $p(z+1∕z)=(z^n +1/z^n)$.

Comment: Nothing relevant that can help to solve the problem i'm stuck

Comment: what is zn, complex analysis?

Comment: its actually z^n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(z + 1/z)^n = \displaystyle\Sigma_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}z^{n-k}z^{-k} = \Sigma_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}z^{n-2k}$

See where expanding the above gets you.

**Detailed answer**
First, consider the case $n$ even:
For $n = 0$ the polynomial is 2.
Suppose that it is possible to find a polynomial for any even number less than $n$.  Then expand
$$(z + 1/z)^n = z^n + nz^{n-2} + ... + nz^{-n + 2} + z^{-n}$$ (verify this expansion with the binomial expansion formula).  So now the problem is reduced to finding a polynomial in $z + 1/z$ that equals
$$-nz^{n-2} + ... - nz^{-n + 2} = -n(z^{n-2} + ... + z^{-n+2})$$ We know that a polynomial $P_{n-2}$ of $z + 1/z$ exists that equals $z^{n-2} + z^{-n+2}$, so the polynomial now has terms $w^n - nP_{n-2}(w)$.  We subsequently do the same thing over and over and, since the exponent of the polynomial to be found decreases by two, the algorithm eventually terminates at the base case and -- voilà -- we get our polynomial.

The case of $n$ odd is similar, only use n = 1 as the base case.

As far as uniqueness, suppose you had two different polynomials $P$ and $Q$ in $w$ that satisfied $P(z + 1/z) = Q(z + 1/z) = z^n + (1/z)^n$.  Then $P - Q$ would have degree at least one or be a constant.  The constant case could not stand, for the constant would have to be zero (meaning $P = Q$).  But if $P - Q$ had degree $n$ then we would have a polynomial with an uncountable number of zeros (i.e., the whole image of $z + 1/z$), which is a no-no by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.  So it must be that there is a unique polynomial satisfying the problem.

Comment: hope you got enough help

Comment: @abdefghijklmnopqrtxyz-stoo Thanks for the boost!

Comment: Thanks a lot @matty_k_walrus i'll give you a boost as soon as i have enough rep

Comment: No problem @hans, just mark my answer as correct.

Comment: @matty_k_walrus For the uniqueness part, how did you found it? I mean is there a chapter that deals with this subject in mathematics? If yes, please tell me i'll be glad to read about it.

Comment: @hans peri The answer is a mix of a few concepts from algebra.  It helps to have higher mathematics courses under your belt, since the problem sets in those courses tend to demand that you recall everything you have learned so far and apply your knowledge in clever ways that weren't taught outright.  As a Ph.D. student I have had quite a few such courses and I've also done contest math problems.  Practice makes perfect!